# SignalR hub self-host or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, signalr

I´m working on a project where a SignalR hub starts up 12 short-running threads (new Thread()). Each thread reports to the client on completion using websockets. The threads are not CPU-intensive, instead they get some information from other web-services.

Now my dilemma is this: Should I create a stand-alone self-hosted signalR hub application that is run as a service or should I just include the hub in my asp.net MVC project?

What is best performance wise?

Comment: You should not be using `multithreading`.

Comment: The talk Damian Edwards and David Fowler gave at NDC London 2013 called 'Using ASP.NET SignalR.. in anger' describes what you want to do and they show example code. http://vimeo.com/84677242 at about 27 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this in .net 4.5 onwards is to do this ***single threaded asynchronous***.

[**ASP.Net should NEVER be creating new threads**](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html). There are huge performance implications when explicitly using threads with ASP.Net.

Also you should know that *threads are an abstraction of limited CPU resources* (you noted as much by stating that your threads are not CPU intensive). In .net 4.5 onwards, that should tell you that you should NOT be using threads. [Instead, in this case you should be using a threadless I/O api to call your webservices.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) I would advise you use the TAP (aka `async` `await`)pattern, which is basically .net 4.5.

This should allow you to scale with a moderately powerful machine to thousands of concurrent request.

If you have all of this in place, using TAP, ASP.Net MVC/IIS will play well with massive parallelization and "threading". In this case I would ***advise highly against using a windows service***, as you will have better stability with IIS as your bootstrapper (handling lifetime, and restarting your service if it dies).

Answer (score 1):

If performance is an issue I would use Thread Pool and not new Thread .

And i will host is a windows service , becuase that would give me more control in term of resources to allocate to the threads.

Comment: ThreadPool uses the thread pool, so I might as well use TPL. What are the advantages? That just uses threads from the thread pool...

Comment: @Dimo no. TPL does not use the ThreadPool. TPL does not care for what parallelizes your Task. TPL is an abstraction layer and pattern library. `Task.Run` (which ships with TPL) uses the `ThreadPool` and quite frankly you should almost never use `Task.Run`.